# ¿Se puede tener más de una etiqueta <footer> en una pagina html?

Tags: html, footer

seguramente sea una pregunta simple, o tonta, pero me ha surgido esa duda en un examen, en el cual, yo puse que si se puede, pero me la han dado por fallada.
He preguntado a chat gpt y me dice que estoy en lo cierto, pero quería que alguno de ustedes, vosotros, me dijerais que pensáis.

Comment: No es una cuestión de opinión, este tipo de preguntas se responden mirando la documentación oficial del estándar o de algún navegador, como Mozilla Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/footer

Comment: En teoría [sí es posible](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-footer-element).

Comment: No es por ánimos de discutir pero existe un gran porcentaje de preguntas en este sitio que se responden mirando la documentación y aún así son bien recibidas. Lo digo porque tiene -1 y a mi me pareció una pregunta interesante.

Comment: @Rubén no cuestiono tu experiencia, pero esta pregunta no tiene respuestas ni comentarios basados en opiniones. La respuesta a si se puede tener más de una etiqueta en una página html, es si, si se puede. Tal y como Pablo y Mateo han compartido y Yussef ah respondido, puedes agregar footers por sección, si tienes 20 secciones, podrías tener 20 footers dentro de la misma página. Ahora, en cuanto a JackOlaf, tiene que apelar con la documentación en mano y ejemplos desde la misma documentación.

Comment: @Excorpion Las preguntas deben jusgarze por su contenido, no por los comentarios o respuestas que tiene. Una mala pregunta puede tener excelentes respuestas. Si ese fuera el caso de esta pregunta, de todas formas podría cerrarse, por ser "mala", aunque también, si el autor original no la mejora, la comunidad podría hacerlo... en un momento dado un moderador de comunidad podría convertirla en wiki de comunidad para que no sea necesario aprobar las sugerencias de edición.

Comment: @Rubén No estoy apelando a la pregunta, estoy apelando a lo dicho sobre "Basado en opiniones". La misma descripción lo dice "Es probable que esta pregunta sea respondida con opiniones más que con hechos y citas." y por ende, esta pregunta no es "basada en opiniones", por que si se puede responder con hechos y con citas, que es lo que se ah hecho de manera pertinente. No quita que la pregunta sea mala por que basta con ir a leer la documentación, pero ese no fue el punto que refuté al comentarte.

Answer (score 5):

Ciertamente existen etiquetas que deberían ser únicas en un documento HTML, tales como: `HTML`, `body`, `head` y `main`

En cambio, la etiqueta [footer](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/footer) **puede estar presente muchas veces en el documento**. El `footer` representa el "pie de página" de una sección, por ejemplo de un `article`, y cómo es posible tener varios `articles`, es evidente que pueden existir muchos `footer` en un mismo documento HTML.

Pero no solo eso, dentro de una misma sección puede tener multiples `footer` sin problema

Por ejemplo, este código

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<title>hola</title>
</head>
<body>
<footer></footer>
<footer></footer>
<footer></footer>
<footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Puedes validarlo en:  h[ttps://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

En teoría se puede. Tu puedes poner tantos `header`, `footer`...

Si en el examen te lo han contado mal, será por la estructura. La estructura correcta de un documento `html` seria:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <!-- Meta, links, <title> -->
  </head>
  <body>
     <header>
        <!-- Contenido del header -->
     </header>
     <main>
        <!-- Contenido de tu main -->
     </main>
     <footer>
        <!-- Contenido del footer -->
     </footer>
 </body>
</html>
```

Así que, en una web html de verdad, no sería un error, aunque en un examen de estructura html si que te lo podrían marcar mal

Un Saludo

Comment: Ya quisiera saber quien le ah dado negativo a esta respuesta, y porqué.

Comment: @Excorpion hay alguien que no puede olvidarse de sus costumbres parece

Comment: Tomo nota de todo. Agradecido